# Mass transit: Need to create and use a wrapper around IConsumer and Consumecontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, masstransit

I've created two projects:

1. A WrapperMassTransit library
2. A Consumer App (Has dependency on WrapperMassTransit)

Main purpose is to decouple mass transit logic from the consumer application

The library contains MassTransit related packages, configurations as well as two wrapper classes:

i) Wrapper for IConsumer

```
public interface IWrapperConsumer<TMessage> : IConsumer where TMessage : class
    {
        Task Consume(WrapperConsumeContext<TMessage> context);
    }
```

ii) Wrapper for ConsumeContext

```
public interface WrapperConsumeContext<T> : ConsumeContext<T> where T : class { }
```

Now, in the Consumer app, I want to consume the incoming message, like so:

```
public class MessageConsumer : IWrapperConsumer<Message>
    {

        public async Task Consume(WrapperConsumeContext<Message> context)
        {
            ..some code
        }
    }
```

The problem is the message is never enqueued and consumed (hit the consume method) unless I use the actual IConsumer and ConsumeContext classes in the consumer app.

I've tried using auto mapper to map the interfaces in startup.cs but that didn't work.

Obviously, these wrappers are unknown to mass transit. So, is it possible to configure mass transit so that it considers my wrapper classes as consumer and consumer context?

EDIT:

As per Chris's solution, I tried using the unit tests approach, however the message goes to skipped queue even though I've configured in receive endpoint, as follows:

```
busFactoryConfigurator.ReceiveEndpoint("message-endpoint", e =>
{
             e.Consumer(typeof(MessageConsumer), type => new MessageConsumer ());
});
```

MessageConsumer:

```
public class MessageConsumer : IHandler<Message>
    {
        public async Task Handle(Message message)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, reconsider what you're attempting to accomplish. An abstraction layer such as this one eventually becomes a worthless leaky abstraction (Google it, you'll find plenty of blog posts showing how bad of an idea it is).

> By the way, *leaky abstraction* is the least colorful metaphor I would use to describe this approach.

`MassTransit.Abstractions` has zero dependencies, and is all that is required to build your consumers and use the related interfaces (including all publishing, sending, etc.). It even runs in Blazer WebAssembly.

Second, if you insist on going down this road instead of creating business value for your application and its customers, [there is an example convention in the unit tests](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/b5b4f508e5f261d6a3cf0029c604452e04666fa3/tests/MassTransit.Tests/Conventional/ConventionConsumer_Specs.cs) that shows how to plug your own conventions into consumer discovery. Mind you, it isn't officially supported but it was designed years ago and the unit tests pass, so maybe it works for you.

> It is also how MassTransit does internal discovery of consumers, so it's probably fine to use.